# Get the names of data frames from a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Say I have the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame()
df2 <- data.frame()
mylist = list(df1, df2)
```

Is there a function that will return me the names of these two data frames, i.e. returns me `'df1' 'df2'`? I know that `names(mylist)` will just return me `NULL`.

Comment: Try to name your dfs in the list `mylist = list(df1 = df1, df2 = df1)`, then simple `names(mylist)` would give you the names.

Comment: What about if the data frames in my list have really long names, and so it doesn't look very tidy to repeat the name?

Comment: How did you get those dfs to your workspace? I rarely manually create lists of dataframes with names as you have shown in the example, usually they are created while reading/processing data within lapply.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) is pretty darn similar. See gregor's answer there for tips on working with lists of data.frames. My answer there is close to akrun's below and uses a regular expression for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

If we create the `list` with `mget`, we can get the `names`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0("df", 1:2))
names(lst1)
#[1] "df1" "df2"
```

Comment: NOTE: this can also work for many datasets.  Suppose if there are 100 data objects like 'df1', 'df2', ...., 'df100', if time and energy persists, one can do `list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, ....df100 = df100)`

Comment: That isn't very helpful for the cases where the dfs are not named sequentially.

Comment: @Borror0 You can use `mget(ls(patterns = "^df\\d+$"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist <- list()
mylist[["df1"]] <-df1
mylist[["df2"]] <-df2
names(mylist)
```

or

```
mylist[[deparse(substitute(df1))]] <-df1
```

Comment: an explanation as to why that would work helps everyone.

Comment: Shen please add more content explaining how this works - currently your post is being flagged because of this.