# Create vector of data frame names from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames, and I want to create a character vector that contains the data frame names that meet a certain criteria.  In this case, I want the names of the data frames that contain at least 1 observation.  I need these names in a vector for use in another function later on.

The list of data frames is created automatically by the split function.  For reproducibility, here's a list of data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))
df3 <- data.frame(replicate(0,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))) #empty

mylist <- list(df1, df2,df3) #create list of data frames

mylist2 <- mylist[sapply(mylist, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0] #subset list so that df's with no observations are dropped
```

Now, what I need is a character vector with the names of the data frames in mylist2.  (In this example, "df1" and "df2".)

Thanks!

Comment: You have to provide your list of dataframes with the names.

Comment: Here is one option `lapply(Filter(length, mylist), names)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944307/get-the-names-of-data-frames-from-a-list/44944323#44944323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to be somewhat automatized, for instance you have a large number of data.frames in your environment, you might want to select them with a pattern matching in one line:

```
mylist = do.call("list", mget(grep("df", ls(), value=T)))
mylist2 <- mylist[sapply(mylist, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]
```

This creates the first list with all data.frames that have "df" in their names, while keeping their names as attributes of the list elements.

Then I apply your filter for 1-element data.frames and you just retrieve the names:

```
names(mylist2)
#### [1] "df1" "df2"
```

Comment: Your second and third line are equivalent to `names(mylist)[sapply(mylist, nrow) > 0]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a named list. Here is how you could do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mylist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)

test <- mylist %>%
  map_int(nrow)

test[test > 0] %>% names()
#[1] "df1" "df2"
```

Comment: Thanks!  The issue is that I have over 250 data frames.  Is there a simple way to assign each data frame a name without having type out "df1 = df1....df250 = df250"?  (I realize this is out of the scope of the original question but a quick search yields no helpful results.)

Comment: If the list has already been created then you could do: 
`names(mylist) <- paste0("df", 1L:length(mylist))`